# Script Tag Interrupts Mutation Observer for Template Tags

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

I'm building a library, that interacts with template tags, and watches for new ones that might be added to the page using a MutationObserver.

```html
<script>
  const upgradeNewNodes = (mutationRecords) => {
    mutationRecords.forEach((mutationRecord) => {
      mutationRecord.addedNodes.forEach((newNode) => {
        if (newNode.matches?.('template')) {
          console.log([...newNode.content.childNodes].map(child => child.nodeName))
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(upgradeNewNodes);
  observer.observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
</script>

<template>
  <span>Beginning</span>
  <script>
    console.log('foo')
  </script>
  <span>Ending</span>
</template>
```

However, when my mutation observer picks up this template tag, it only sees **up to the script tag**.

```
// [object NodeList] (4)
[#text,<span/>,#text,<script/>]
```

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/JRJurman/pen/WNLEaqp?editors=1001

*My current hypothesis is that the HTML parser is stopped when it hits the script tag.*

In my actual library, I can only process the contents once, so adding another MutationObserver for the content in the template isn't really an option.

Is there a way to know when the template has completely loaded? Are there other ways that I can progressively catch template tags being added to the page (other than MutationObserver)?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable. This is preferrable to a link to codepen.

Comment: You can create a new observer for the template's `content` and it'll see the nodes after script.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I'll make this more clear in the summary, but in the actual program, I can only process the content of the template once, so I need to know for sure once it's done, not in a partial state

Comment: @wOxxOm - that being said, if you want to add that as an answer, that could be a useful option for other people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential option here appears to be watching for nodes **right after a template tag** - these are almost always guaranteed to exist, because there are always TEXT nodes before, between, and after elements.

```html
<script>
  const upgradeNewNodes = (mutationRecords) => {
    mutationRecords.forEach((mutationRecord) => {
      mutationRecord.addedNodes.forEach((newNode) => {
        // check if this node is after a template (if it is, process that template)
        // this is almost always guaranteed to exist, and be a TEXT node
        if (newNode.previousSibling?.matches?.('template')) {
          console.log([...newNode.previousSibling.content.childNodes].map(child => child.nodeName))
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(upgradeNewNodes);
  observer.observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
</script>

<template>
  <span>Beginning</span>
  <script>
    console.log('foo')
  </script>
  <span>Ending</span>
</template>
```

Results in:

```
// [object NodeList] (7)
[#text,<span/>,#text,<script/>,#text,<span/>,#text]
```

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/JRJurman/pen/jOXLQmY?editors=1001